# Смена цвета текста в ячейке в QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qtablewidget, qstyleditemdelegate

Как менять цвет текста в ячейке `QTableWidget`, в зависимости от содержимого?

При смене значения переменной `eq_adress` "***`Online`***" или "***`Offline`***" - цвет текста не меняется, остается тот цвет, который определился первым, а надо, чтоб менялся:

при `eq_adress` = ***'`Online`'* - `зеленый`**, при eq_adress == ***'`Offline`'* - `красный`**

```
try:
    eq_adress = 'Online' # в данную переменную передается значение Online или Offline
    if eq_adress == 'Online':
        ui.tableWidget_4.setItem(0, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(eq_adress))
        ui.tableWidget_4.item(0, 2).setForeground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0)))  # Цвет текста - зеленый
    elif eq_adress == 'Offline':
        ui.tableWidget_4.setItem(0, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(eq_adress))
        ui.tableWidget_4.item(0, 2).setForeground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0)))  # Цвет текста - красный
    else:
        pass
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Класс **QStyledItemDelegate** предоставляет средства отображения и редактирования для элементов данных из модели.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QStyledItemDelegate, QTableWidget 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPalette


class ColorDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.data() == 'Online':
            option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor("green"))
        elif index.data() == 'Offline':
            option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor("red"))
        QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QTableWidget(3, 3)
    w.setItemDelegate(ColorDelegate())
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подскажите кусок кода, при тех же условиях сменить цвет текста у всей строки, а не только у одной ячейки.

Comment: @YanWolf , пожалуйста,  задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1439274/Как-сменить-цвет-текста-всей-строки-по-условию-ячейки-этой-строки-pyqt5