# Как сменить цвет текста всей строки QTableWidget по условию ячейки этой строки PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qtablewidget

Как переписать этот код, чтобы по условию изменяло цвет текста во всех ячейках строки где условие выполнилось?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QStyledItemDelegate, QTableWidget 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPalette


class ColorDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.data() == 'Online':
            option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor("green"))
        elif index.data() == 'Offline':
            option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor("red"))
        QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QTableWidget(3, 3)
    w.setItemDelegate(ColorDelegate())
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class ColorDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    signalColor = pyqtSignal(str, int)
    
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.column() == 1:                                        # !!!
            if index.data() == 'Online':
                option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor("green"))
                self.signalColor.emit("green", index.row())
            elif index.data() == 'Offline':
                option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor("red"))
                self.signalColor.emit("red", index.row())
            else:  
                self.signalColor.emit("black", index.row())
                
        QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(3, 3)
        self.delegate = ColorDelegate() 
        self.delegate.signalColor.connect(self.signal_color)
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        
        for r in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            for c in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(r, c, QTableWidgetItem(f"{r}-{c}")) 
        
        
    def signal_color(self, text, row):
        for col in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):    
            item = QTableWidgetItem()   
            item = self.tableWidget.item(row, col)
            if item:
                self.tableWidget.item(row, col).setForeground(QColor(text))
     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 13, QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(400, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]